# Fail to update composer in Yii2? Timezone fail

Tags: php, date, datetime, yii2

I got this error when i try to update my composer. Strangely this fails in my cloud server but not in my localhost

It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone iden
      tifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

This code should be placed in your php.ini file and index.php. If the error keeps poping in the cloud and not your server, then probably they should put this in php.ini.